# Random images with caption on pageload

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I have a working code for loading random images on page load, using an array. How could I add captions to it? Which is the best way: should I use another array to store the captions or? Any suggestions appreciated!

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images=new Array(); // regular array (add an optional integer
        images[0]="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/a5/47/45/a5474577f4a4ae93c85db719d0cbafd4.jpg";
        images[1]="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e6/41/74/e64174e355f78a0f07e951bcec62ca96.jpg";
        images[2]="https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7abHrsGbV10rCeze/giphy.gif";
        images[3]="https://media.giphy.com/media/Bbt5FxRiArl3a/giphy.gif";
        images[4]="http://2ca54c85d3f608494402-1c6b4b69d2498d95ab6e291a3fb28b64.r36.cf1.rackcdn.com/16/1/large.jpg";
// Preload
$(images).each(function(){
    $("<img/>")[0].src = this;
});

// Random index
var randomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * images.length );

// Call backstretch the first time
$.backstretch(images[randomNumber], {duration: 30000, fade: 1200});

// Change images after that with setInterval
setInterval(function() {
        index = Math.floor( Math.random() * images.length );
        $.backstretch(images[index], {duration: 30000, fade: 1200});
    }, 30000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use 1 array (of objects) to keep things better organized.

So your array items would look something like this:

```
images[0] = {url : "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/a5/47/45/a5474577f4a4ae93c85db719d0cbafd4.jpg", caption : "awesome image"};
```

Then you could set the image and the caption using your same computed index.

Create a single function that updates the image and caption and call it with sentInterval. Your code will be cleaner that way. So, for example:

Declare your function:

```
function setRandomImage(imgs) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length);    
    $.backstretch(imgs[index].url);  
    $("#caption").html(imgs[index].caption); 
}
```

Declare your array:

```
var images = new Array();
    images[0] = {url : "http://blah0.jpg"};
    images[1] = {url : "http://blah1.jpg"};
    images[2] = {url : "http://blah2.jpg"};
```

Call your function on your array, every 3 seconds:

```
setInterval(setRandomImage, 3000, images);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it but didn't work really. My preload function is skipped, after the given duration, the images are showing up, but without their caption. Did I miss something?

Comment: Did you add a caption div to your page? Something like <div id="caption"></div>

Comment: I missed that, thanks! Also a problem was that the setInterval function's curly bracket was closed before initializing the caption. The caption is working!
Now the problem is that my preload function is ignored, so the first image is not shown at the page load.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle of your current code? If not, could you update your question's code, or mark this question as answered and ask another question?

Comment: I updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0hmspsoa/5/). I simplified it a bit because I couldn't figure out how the rest of your HTML was structured. I also changed the duration to 3 seconds and added a console call so you can see the changes (you will want to remove this on your live site). Finally I commented out the preload as it causes the page to do nothing while it loads, but if you want/need it you can un-comment that line and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate, that you spent a lot of time solving my problem! It is finally working! :) Thanks again!!